# Regex is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to create a simple validation method with jQuery, but without a plugin. So I made this code:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.validate = function () {
    var emailRegex = '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
    var error = false;
    if ($('#vorname').val() == "") {
      $('#vorname').after('<span class="error">Name fehlt</span>');
      error = "true";
    }
    if ($('#nachname').val() == "") {
      $('#nachname').after('<span class="error">Name fehlt</span>');
      error = "true";
    }
    if ($('#email').val() == "") {
      $('#email').after('<span class="error">Email fehlt</span>');
      error = "true";
    } else if (!emailRegex.test($('#email').val())) {
      $('#email').after('<span class="error">Keine gültige Email</span>');
      error = "true";
    }
    if (error == true) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return;
      true;
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#button').click(function () {
    $('#button').validate();
  });
});
```

But I'm getting always the message that my regex test isn't a function. What's the issue?

Comment: You might find the discussion in question [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) interesting as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

```
var emailRegex = '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
```

You [might want to write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var emailRegex = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$');
// or simpler
var emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/;
```

Comment: now i got the problem that the email isnt valid also when its a real email adress

Comment: Follow the link in my comment to your question for other/better expressions to validate addresses. Also: only one question per question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `emailRegex` is defined as `String`.
Define it as regexp like this.

`emailRegex = /hogehoge/`